# Hazelcast PredicateBuilder with nested key

Tags: java, hazelcast, predicate, predicatebuilder

I am trying to add an entrylistener to my hazelcast map using a predicate to filter the entries.

The method I am calling is:

```
String addEntryListener(MapListener listener,
Predicate<K,V> predicate,
boolean includeValue)
```

I am trying to build a predicate to filter by my key. My keys are of type `HazelKey` which have the fields:

```
KeyOne keyOne;
KeyTwo keyTwo;
KeyThree keyThree;
```

Then these three Keys have the field:

```
String code
```

Therefore i am trying to do something along the lines of:

```
PredicateBuilder predicate = EntryObject.key().get("keyOne").get("code").equal("1234");
```

to build a predicate to filter all the entries with the keyOne value 1234.

However once the listener has been added, the entries get updated, hazelcast throws the error:

```
Caused by: com.hazelcast.query.QueryException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no suitable accessor for 'code' on class 'class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy45'
```

I believe this is because the predicateBuilder is just ignoring the top level 'KeyOne' paramater and just using 'code' so my question is: How do I do this multilevel predicatebuilding?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not too familiar with `PredicateBuilder`, but I believe this should work for you:

`import static com.hazelcast.query.Predicates.equal;
[...]
Predicate p = equal("keyOne.code", 1234);`